# Help with comparing opamp noise specs

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit, noise, datasheet

I need a DIP package quad opamp which has better output noise than LM324, anything less than 5mV output noise floor would be great.

I could only come across with the following:

LM324: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosc16d/snosc16d.pdf

TL074: https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tl074-ep

OP470: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/OP470.pdf

What parameters in data-sheet should be looked at to compare the output noise of the above opamps?

(I know suggestions are not appreciated but would be nice if you have experience with a better(very low noise) IC alternative to LM324)

Comment: 5 mV noise over what bandwidth?  Or what is the noise spectral density you need?  I'd think nearly all op-amps would have less than 5 mV of output noise over a reasonable bandwidth.

Comment: For BW I can say that the signal output will be a 10mV stair-case increase at each 500us. So basically DC but varying each 500us. So even up to 50us setting time is fine. When the noise floor is thick like 50mV I cannot distinguish the difference between two consecutive stir steps. I need lower output noise floor.

Comment: If you have tens of mV of noise it's not coming from the op-amp, it's being amplified by the op-amp.

Comment: should I RC filter the input you mean? But I still would like to use  better opamp than antique LM324. Are the alternatives in question better?

Comment: Low noise design MAY include an input filter, but also requires things like careful layout, routing, decoupling, shielding, and isolation, as well as component selection.  As to which amplifier is "better" it depends on many things you haven't specified.  (Gain, offset voltage, slew rate, desired supply, signal source and impedance, etc.

Comment: The noise of the system is likely determined by the circuitry surrounding the opamp, not the opamp itself. To get a complete picture we'd need to view your schematic.

Comment: Given the stated constraints, you could just reduce the bandwidth until your noise goal is met.

Comment: @user_1818839 In practice what does it mean? Adding RC filters at the output or input.

Answer (score 2):

Read a good tutorial, e.g.

[Analog Devices - Op Amp Noise](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-047.pdf)

[Texas instruments - Understanding Op Amp Noise](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa345/sboa345.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

For most opamp circuits, the noise you see at the output is predominantly amplified input noise.  So you want to look at your input noise specs, both voltage and current noise.  When the surrounding circuit input impedance is significantly higher than their ratio, current noise will dominate the results (since it causes voltage noise across the input impedance), similarly if it is lower, the voltage noise will dominate.

Your choice of opamp will in general depend on the surrounding circuitry, particularly the input: JFET input opamps tend to produce best results with high impedance designs, BJT inputs tend to work better with intermediate to lower impedances.

If you have a smooth well-bypassed power supply, you'll need less PSRR than otherwise.  The LM324 is a quad opamp: obviously if you use the 3 other opamps for different purposes, you want high crossover suppression and it depends on what the others do whether they'll cause problems.  And so on.

Just waving model numbers around is of moderate use when the details of your circuit are in the dark.  And then we haven't even gotten to requirements about operating currents and operating voltages and how close you want the output swing to the rails at which output impedance in which time.

Answer (score 0):

Define your overall design specs. Then choose these parameters and narrow your selection. You ought have at least half a dozen parameters of importance.

e.g. **including:** Rail to rail, ultra-low noise BW required might be 20x your step frequency of 2kHz or higher which if using low gain <=100, will required LP filtering.  OPA1655 is a possible choice using ~ 1~10K resistors.

https://www.ti.com/amplifier-circuit/op-amps/precision/overview.html

Comment: Hello I really need DIP package. How about this one https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc6044.pdf?ts=1645218522176 ?

Comment: and this one https://datasheet.octopart.com/LMC660CN/NOPB-National-Semiconductor-datasheet-9775193.pdf

Comment: OPA1655 = 4 , LMC6044 = 65, LMC660 =22 nV/√Hz  @ 1kHz [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=diy+soldering+SOIc